# Prove U=Z where addition is regular addition in Z, but multiplication is defined by a*b=a IS NOT A RING

Tags: abstract-algebra

Ok,so clearly

1. a+b ∈ R
2. a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c
3. a+b = b+a
4. a+0 = a = 0+a, 0 ∈ R  a ∈ R
5. a+x = 0, x = -a ∈R

now

6. a ∈ R b ∈ R and ab = a ∈R
7. a(bc) = a(b) = a

   (ab)c = (a)c = a
8. a(b+c) = ab+ac = a+a

   (a+b)c = ac+bc = a+b

Why is this not a ring? It seems to me that it satisfies all the axioms

Comment: So according to how it is defined $a(b+c)=a\neq ab+ac=a+a$.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhh ok thank you